# How to log out of GitHub account in Git Bash?

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-18.04, git-config

I accidentally made a typo while logging into my GitHub after a fresh Linux installation in Git Bash. Now everytime I try to push to my GitHub account, I am unable to push it. 
I am using KDE Neon based on Ubuntu LTS 18.04
Can somebody help me in logging out of GitHub.

Edit 1: I just made the remote repository by using `git remote add origin <https url>` and then used git push. It asked for my username and password where all the problem happened. Now whenever I try to use `git push` again, it just takes an enormous amount of time and then give the error that it is unable to push after a few minutes.

Comment: Have you registered a ssh key ?

Comment: Please mention the command you typed and the error message that you get in return.

Comment: Please add the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

**In Ubuntu** if you colned using ssh

```
git config --global --unset-all
```

run bove command then remove you ssh key form `~/.ssh`

Answer (score 1):

Remove your SSH keys from ~/.ssh.

If you want to remove your user settings:

```
git config --global --unset user.name
git config --global --unset user.email
```

Or

If you want to remove all your global settings:

```
git config --global --unset-all
```

Comment: I removed all the global variables by the above command but I could not find the SSH key file ~/.ssh in my home directory. I used `ls -a` to check for all the files but it wasn't there.